# Possible to eliminate "NOT IN" subquery from MySQL delete?

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery, mariadb

I've got two InnoDB tables, let's call them tableD and tableC.  TableD has rows with a varchar primary key called id.  TableC has rows with a BIGINT primary key called seq and another varchar column called f_id.  f_id's values are not unique, and correspond to the id column in tableC.

What I am trying to achieve is to delete all rows from tableD, except for those that match the f_id column in any rows in tableC with seq column value greater than a specific value.

Here's the query I have right now:

```
delete d from tableD as d
where d.id not in (
    select c.f_id from tableC as c
    where seq>1401399893702598
);
```

While this does the job, this query will be run against large tables, in the 10s of GB range with millions of rows.  It doesn't need to be real-time, but faster is better.  So I am trying to find out if it is possible to eliminate this subquery, possibly replacing it with a join.  I think I have to keep this as single query since rows could be added to either of the tables at any time, and those new rows should not be deleted for any reason.

I have failed at all attempts so far.  The closed I have got is the following query which deletes only the rows I want to keep and leaves everything else:

```
delete d from tableD as d
    left join tableC as c on d.id=c.f_id
    where c.seq>1401399893702598;
```

I am using MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the condition on `seq` to the `on` clause and test for no matches in the `where` clause:

```
delete d
    from tableD as d left join
         tableC as c
         on d.id = c.f_id and c.seq > 1401399893702598
    where c.f_id is null;
```